# PLS-00221 'to_date' is not a procedure or undefined error and converting dates separated by period

Tags: plsql, procedure

I want to convert an IN parameter which is in type of varchar2 to a date so that I can pull the data from the database between the two input dates. I have one problem and one question.

Problem is that I am getting the error

> "PLS-00221: to_date is not a procedure or undefined"

when I have the following code:

```
create or replace procedure display_users(          pi_date1       in varchar2,
                                                    pi_date2       in varchar2,
                                                    po_userc       out sys_refcursor) is

begin

  if pi_date1 is not null then
    to_date(pi_date1, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
  end if;

  begin
    open po_userc for
      select ... 
        from ...
       where ...
         and ...
         and t.inserted_date betweeen pi_date1 and pi_date2 ;
  end;

end;
```

I am not very familiar with pl/sql procedures, I tried lots of other ways to make it work but I wasn't able to do it.

The question is that in the database my dates are like this: '16.08.2018 10:30:48'   (I cannot change the data format in database)

The date part is separated by periods (.) . Will `to_date(pi_date1, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');`  work since date is separated by "/" ?

Comment: Try this pi_date1 := to_date(pi_date1, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');

Comment: @Ovoxo you cant assign date to varchar2

Comment: @hotfix that's true my fault!

Comment: Your cursor does not look quite correct yet. what type is `inserted_date`? why is `date1` and `date2` of type `varchar2`? if you convert `date1` to `date`, you should also convert `date2` to `date`

Comment: inserted_date is type date and I was asked to create date1 and date2 as varchar2. I am going to convert both of them I just did not post it here. Thanks for the help, both of you

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if the parameters matched the datatype of the column? Then you just pass in dates, and it is up to the caller of the procedure to pass valid values. In the version above, you have to pass strings in a specific format, but you can't tell what format that should be without looking at the procedure code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as the error message already says, `to_date` is not a procedure. `to_date` is a function and a function always returns a value. You must assign this value to a variable.

```
declare
  v_date  date;
begin
  v_date := to_date(pi_date1, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
end;
/
```

When converting to a date you have to pay attention to the format. Is there a separator between day, month and year, hour, Minute and seconds? If it is a Point (`.`) then you have to specify it as a Format.

If your string looks like this: `01.01.2000 01:01:01` 
Then your format must look like this: `'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS'`

If your string looks like this: `01/01/2000 01:01:01`
Then your format must look like this: `'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'`